# Run process with gdb and detach it

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to run a process with `gdb`, modify some memory and then `detach` from the process afterwards?

I can't start the process from outside of `gdb` as I need to modify the memory, before the first instruction is executed.

When you `detach` from a process started with `gdb`, `gdb` will hang, but killing `gdb` from another process makes the debugged process still running.

I currently use the following script to launch the process:

```
echo '# custom gdb function that finds the entry_point an assigns it to $entry_point_address
entry_point
b *$entry_point_address
run
set *((char *)0x100004147) = 0xEB
set *((char *)0x100004148) = 0xE2
detach # gdb hangs here
quit # quit never gets executed
' | gdb -quiet "$file"
```

This happens in both of my `gdb` versions:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1824)
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822 + reverse.put.as patches v0.4)
```

Comment: What?  You're using `6.3`?  That was released almost a decade back.

Comment: @devnull It's the newest version released by Apple, which includes OS X related features. As Apple is preferring `llvm+clang` instead of `gcc`, it makes sense that they would also prefer `lldb` over `gdb`.

Comment: Why do you need to detach?  Why not just leave gdb running?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I would prefer if I didn't have multiple instances of gdb running, just because `detach` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that you can't detach from an inferior processes that was started directly under `gdb`, however, something like the following might work for you, this is based on a recent `gdb`, I don't know how much of this will work on version 6.3.

Create a small shell script, like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo $$
sleep 10
exec /path/to/your/program arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now start this up, spot the pid from `echo $$`, and attach to the shell script like this `gdb -p PID`.  Once attached you can:

```
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
(gdb) catch exec
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
[New process NEW-PID]
process NEW-PID is executing new program: /path/to/your/program
[Switching to process NEW-PID]

Catchpoint 1 (exec'd /path/to/your/program), 0x00007f40d8e9fc80 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

You can now modify the child process as required.  Once you're finished just do:

```
(gdb) detach
```

And `/path/to/your/program` should resume (or start in this case) running.